# filtering a field of json by a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, filter

I am trying to filter a json field by a string with javascript. More clearly, I have a search box, and a fake return json. When I press some letters in the input box, an ajax call should filter my fake response according to the input string, thus I can show the result.

My input box and call function with my fake ajax response is working fine. But I have trouble with filtering it.

```
var res = response.filter(function (i, n) {
    return String(n.Name).toLowerCase().indexOf(String(srt).toLowerCase()) === 0;
});
```

Here is my fake JSON response:

```
[{ "Name": "ALICE", "Close": 7.12, "UpDown": 1 }, { "Name": "MICHAEL", "Close": 110.78, "UpDown": 1 }]
```

`n.Name` returns `undefined`. So, the `res` becomes an object with `undefined`'s. In this case, if I enter `und` for example, all of the elements are shown; if I enter something else, none of the elements can pass the filter.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: You have the arguments reversed. `n` is actually the index and `i` is actually the element in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `.filter` syntax mixed up. You can check it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

The first argument is the value, while the second is the index. What ends up happening with your code is that you're trying to find the `Name` property of the index 0, which is causing your `undefined` error.